# How to resolve "Useless use of ucfirst in void context at C:/Program Files/perl/lib/File/Spec/Win32.pm"?

Tags: perl, perl-module

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  -w
use strict;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;

my $idividi = "http://www.idividi.com.mk";
my $tocka = "http://tocka.com.mk";

sub check_server() {
  my @urlList = ($idividi, $tocka);
  print "Checking server availability...\n";

  foreach my $server_endpoint (@urlList){
     my $uaObject = LWP::UserAgent->new;
     my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $server_endpoint);
     my $response = $uaObject->request($request);

     if(length($response->decoded_content) != 0) {
        print "$server_endpoint ---> HTTPS network connectivity:        AVAILABLE\n";
     } else {
        print "$server_endpoint ---> HTTPS network connectivity: NOT AVAILABLE\n";
     } 
 }
```

}

---

When I try to run this, I got the error:
"Useless use of ucfirst in void context at C:/Program Files/perl/lib/File/Spec/Win32.pm".

I can not find any possible solution on the net.

Comment: `use Carp::Always` and get a full stack trace of this warning (not error) message

Comment: Win32.pm line 388. But I think that this is not related to the module but something in my code. On line 388 there is :ucfirst($1);

Comment: Does the script gets terminated when this message appears or it continues after that?

Comment: No, it's just a warning I think.

Comment: What version of File::Spec::Win32 do you have? Check by running `perl -MFile::Spec::Win32 -e"print $File::Spec::Win32::VERSION"`

Comment: Can you please upload your `C:\Program Files\perl\lib\File\Spec\Win32.pm` to http://pastebin.com/ or something? I strongly suspect it's been corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your `File/Spec/Win32.pm` file. You should reinstall the whole of `File::Spec` from the command line with

```
cpan File::Spec
```

The latest version 3.62 has this long statement at line 385

```
my $volume = $first =~ s{ \A ([A-Za-z]:) ([\\/]?) }{}x  # drive letter
           ? ucfirst( $1 ).( $2 ? "\\" : "" )
       : $first =~ s{ \A (?:\\\\|//) ([^\\/]+)
             (?: [\\/] ([^\\/]+) )?
                 [\\/]? }{}xs           # UNC volume
       ? "\\\\$1".( defined $2 ? "\\$2" : "" )."\\"
       : $first =~ s{ \A [\\/] }{}x         # root dir
       ? "\\"
       : "";
```

and there is no way that that use of `ucfirst` can cause the *Useless use* warning.

---

You may also be interested in this refactoring of your code, which avoids a few less than ideal constructs

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use LWP::UserAgent;
use URI;

my ( $idividi, $tocka ) = qw/ www.idividi.com.mk tocka.com.mk /;

check_servers( $idividi, $tocka );

sub check_servers {
    my @url_list = @_;

    print "Checking server availability...\n";

    my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    my $url = URI->new('http://example.com/');

    for my $server (@url_list) {

        $url->host($server);
        my $response = $ua->get($url);
        my $avail = length( $response->decoded_content ) != 0;

        printf "%s ---> HTTPS network connectivity: %s\n",
            $server,
            $avail ? 'AVAILABLE' : 'NOT AVAILABLE';
    }
}
```

#### output

```
Checking server availability...
www.idividi.com.mk ---> HTTPS network connectivity: AVAILABLE
tocka.com.mk ---> HTTPS network connectivity: AVAILABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `perl -w`. It enables warnings *globally*, even within modules that may not have been written with those warnings in mind.

If you want to enable warnings, `use warnings` will enable that for the current file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11481702)

Comment: @kaklon Er, this is definitely an answer to the question. The problem (i.e, the warnings) is being caused by the inappropriate use of the `-w` flag; replacing it with `use warnings` is the solution.

Comment: Sorry about that, It wasn't clear to me that this was in fact the answer to the problem.